# How to interact with each element of an ArrayType column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I have an ArrayType column in pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(((1,[]),(2,[1,2,3]),(3,[-2])),schema=StructType([StructField("a",IntegerType()),StructField("b",ArrayType(IntegerType()))]))
df.show()
output:
+---+---------+
|  a|        b|
+---+---------+
|  1|       []|
|  2|[1, 2, 3]|
|  3|     [-2]|
```

Now, I want to be able to interact with each element of column `b`, Like,

1. Divide each element by 5
   output:

```
+---+---------------+
|  a|              b|
+---+---------------+
|  1|             []|
|  2|[0.2, 0.4, 0.6]|
|  3|         [-0.4]|
+---+---------------+
```

2. Add to each element etc.

How do I go about such transformations where some operator or function is applied to each element of the array type columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`tranform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html?highlight=transform#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) function. Transform enables to apply computation on each element of an array.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Spark < 3.1.0
df.withColumn("b", F.expr("transform(b, x ->  x / 5)")).show()

"""
+---+---------------+
|  a|              b|
+---+---------------+
|  1|             []|
|  2|[0.2, 0.4, 0.6]|
|  3|         [-0.4]|
+---+---------------+
"""

# Spark >= 3.1.0

df.withColumn("b", F.transform("b", lambda x: x / 5)).show()
"""
+---+---------------+
|  a|              b|
+---+---------------+
|  1|             []|
|  2|[0.2, 0.4, 0.6]|
|  3|         [-0.4]|
+---+---------------+
"""
```

Comment: Ahh yess!! The documentation says : "Returns an array of elements after applying a transformation to each element in the input array.". I think they should have documented this under the array section in the documentation. And the name should not be so generic  that gives no hint to google that it can show this under search results. Thank you for quick help and your time @Nithish

Comment: I've searched for hours to find this! Thank you! One small addition for possible future readers. If you `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`, you must not use `f.fun()` within the transform expression. Just use the bare function name.